# View Direction dont change to rtl in XLSX-Style

Tags: javascript, excel, sheetjs

I want to export a rtl direction xlsx file using [XLSX-Style](https://github.com/markatil/xlsx-style)
According to official documents I use below code to change view direction to rtl

```
    if (!wb.Workbook) wb.Workbook = {};
    if (!wb.Workbook.Views) wb.Workbook.Views = [];
    if (!wb.Workbook.Views[0]) wb.Workbook.Views[0] = {};
    wb.Workbook.Views[0].RTL = true;
```

but again exported view direction is ltr

Comment: I am having the same difficulties. with `xlsx-style` the `RTL` property seems to not be supported... Any success on your end @mohammad-didehvar ?

Comment: as I remember i had fixed it but i'm not in that company and forget how to fix that :D